# How to get matrix of sums instead of distances

Tags: r, matrix, sum

Title says it clearly. My problem is simple. Suppose I have vector x:

```
x <- c(13,10,9,5)

# this function gives only distances
dist(x)
  1 2 3
2 3    
3 4 1  
4 8 5 4

Instead of distance I would like to have sums like this:
# sum matrix
  1  2  3
2 23    
3 22 19  
4 18 15 14
```

**How to do it?** Is there some argument in `dist` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use outer function

```
as.dist(outer(x,x,'+'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer`

```
sums <- outer(x, x, `+`)[-1, ]
```

To make it symmetric, use `uppertri`

```
sums[upper.tri(sums)] <- NA
```

Comment: If you want to get the matrix as in the example, just use `print(sums, na.print = "")`, +1!